# is it possible to break Singleton using Deserialize or cloning or multiple threads if we have implemented Singleton using Enum?

Tags: java, singleton

is it possible to break Singleton using Deserialize or cloning or multiple threads if we have implemented Singleton using Enum ?

Comment: No. That is why it is recommended. [See also](https://java-design-patterns.com/patterns/singleton/).

Comment: But the flipside is that serialization / deserialization of singletons is *problematic* if the singleton object is statefull by design.